# "Documents.library-ms" is no longer working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

When I click on the browse button in various applications the following message comes up.

> "Documents.library-ms" is no longer working.
>   This library can be safely deleted from your computer.
>   Folders that have been included will not be affected.

Here is a screenshot

[image: "Documents.library-ms" is no longer working.]

I'm able to press "OK" and continue without any problems, but it's annoying and I'm concerned that it could be an indication of a deeper problem.

Why does this message appear and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading ["Documents.library-ms" is no longer working.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/documentslibrary-ms-is-no-longer-working/0845e8c3-4097-47e8-887a-ae875aa7c4b6) I figured out how to fix this

In explorer
[image: explorer]

Delete each library that causes the error dialog to appear.

Right click on the libraries and select "Restore default libraries"

[image: Restore default libraries]

The dialog box no longer appears and the libraries can be opened in explorer

[image: restored libraries]